# R getting columns that follow specific pattern

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to select specific columns from R dataframe and I am using below line and it works fine:

```
maindata <- rbind(maindata, dat[c('Segment','hWave')])
```

But then I want to select columns that are names such as `Q2_1`, `Q2_2` up to `Q2_18`. How could I do that effectively? I can type individual column name but that won't be efficient.

The line below gives me an error.

```
  maindata <- rbind(maindata, dat[c('Segment','hWave','Q2_1':'Q2_18')])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
maindata <- rbind(maindata, dat[c("Segment","hWave",paste("Q2",1:18,sep="_"))])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `select` from the `dplyr` package:

```
select(dat, starts_with("Q2_"))
```